# How to update dynamodb table using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

How to enable "PointInTimeRecoverySpecification" for existing dynamodb tables by using cloud formation.
I have tried like below:

```
Resources: 
  mytableenablerecovery: 
    Properties: 
       AttributeDefinitions: 
         - 
          AttributeName: ArtistId
          AttributeType: S
        KeySchema: 
          - 
          AttributeName: ArtistId
          KeyType: HASH
      PointInTimeRecoverySpecification: 
         PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
      TableName: mytablename123
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
```

But it is creating the new table if not exists otherwise it is throwing the error "mytablename123 already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-"

Answer (score 0):

[While the list is expanding](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/276), [only some resource types currently support importing existing resources into CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html)

Luckily, [`AWS::DynamoDB::Table`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html) is currently one of those resource types

To import existing resources of one of those supported resource types into CloudFormation, they must be imported using change sets [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)